# Google Apps - Email

Tags: g-suite

I have setup the DNS records for the oxy.gr domain and online network tools verify that the MX records point to all google mail servers.

For some reason whenever I try to send an e-mail from gmail to an e-mail account XXX@oxy.gr I get the following error:

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 553 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1) (state 14).

**DNS settings for this domain:**

```
207.44.138.195 / 24 PTR mail.oxy.gr.

207.44.138.195 / 24 PTR oxy.gr.

ftp.oxy.gr. CNAME oxy.gr.

mail.oxy.gr. A 207.44.138.195

ns.oxy.gr. A 207.44.138.195

oxy.gr. NS ns.oxy.gr.

oxy.gr. A 207.44.138.195

oxy.gr. MX (5) ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

oxy.gr. MX (10) ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

oxy.gr. MX (10) ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

oxy.gr. MX (15) ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

oxy.gr. MX (15) ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

oxy.gr. TXT v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

webmail.oxy.gr. A 207.44.138.195

www.oxy.gr. CNAME oxy.gr.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've setup the MX records correctly, but you have not completed the mail setup on the Google side. You should have something like mail.oxy.gr pointing to ghs.google.com. It has been a long time since I did it for a domain that I host there and I cannot guide you from memory, but you have not completed all the steps required to host email directed to oxy.gr on Google Apps.